# How to display percentage label in histogram plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I managed to create a plot that shows the number of records per class label for each age in my Pandas dataframe. But I would also like to see a percentage label for the "non functional" class in each age group.

The Python code for the graph is

```
train['age_wpt'] = train.date_recorded.str.split('-').str.get(0).apply(int) - train.construction_year

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.hist([
        train[(train.status_group=='functional') & (train.age_wpt < 60.0) & (train.age_wpt >= 0.0)]['age_wpt'],
        train[(train.status_group=='non functional') & (train.age_wpt < 60.0) & (train.age_wpt >= 0.0)]['age_wpt'],
        train[(train.status_group=='functional needs repair') & (train.age_wpt < 60.0) & (train.age_wpt >= 0.0)]['age_wpt']
        ], 
         stacked=True, color = ['b','r','y'],
         bins = 30,label = ['functional','non functional', 'functional needs repair'])
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Number of records')
plt.legend()
```

This results in the following graph
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> normed : boolean, optional
>       If `True`, the first element of the return tuple will
>       be the counts normalized to form a probability density, i.e.,
>       `` n/(len(x)`dbin) ``, i.e., the integral of the histogram will sum
>       to 1. If *stacked* is also *True*, the sum of the histograms is
>       normalized to 1.
>       Default is `False`

```
plt.hist([
        train[(train.status_group=='functional') & (train.age_wpt < 60.0) & (train.age_wpt >= 0.0)]['age_wpt'],
        train[(train.status_group=='non functional') & (train.age_wpt < 60.0) & (train.age_wpt >= 0.0)]['age_wpt'],
        train[(train.status_group=='functional needs repair') & (train.age_wpt < 60.0) & (train.age_wpt >= 0.0)]['age_wpt']
        ], 
         stacked=False, color = ['b','r','y'], normed=True
         bins = 30,label = ['functional','non functional', 'functional needs repair'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to show the percentage of each red part **per age**. Normed=True gives the percentage of each bar to the total of all bars in the chart.

Comment: Could you please provide the data?  `data = {'functional': train[(train.status_group=='functional') & (train.age_wpt < 60.0) & (train.age_wpt >= 0.0)]['age_wpt'], ''non functional': train[(train.status_group=='non functional') & (train.age_wpt < 60.0) & (train.age_wpt >= 0.0)]['age_wpt'], "functional needs repair": train[(train.status_group=='functional needs repair') & (train.age_wpt < 60.0) & (train.age_wpt >= 0.0)]['age_wpt']]}`

Comment: Also, try with `stacked=False`

Comment: The data comes from this link https://www.drivendata.org/competitions/7/